# spring AOP with ProxyFactoryBean not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aop

Please find the class structure as below and help to find anything missing here.
Unable to get the SOP mentioned in the before method.

```
public class HijackBeforeMethod implements MethodBeforeAdvice {
@Override
public void before(Method arg0, Object[] arg1, Object arg2) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("BEFORE METHOD CALL : additional concern before actual logic");
    System.out.println("Method : " + arg0);

}
}
```

The Main class as below

```
@RestController
public class A {

 @Autowired
 Dao b;
 ...
 b.print(); //This should call the before method
}
```

The Dao class as below

```
Public class DaoImpl implements Dao{
 @Autowired
 Datasource ds
 public void print(){
 .....
 }
}
```

the rest-servlet.xml context file entries as below

```
 <bean id="hijackBeforeMethodBean" class="com.scb.cadm.aop.HijackBeforeMethod" />
  <bean id="b" class="DaoImpl"></bean>
  <bean id="proxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">/>
     <property name="target" ref="b"></property>
     <property name="interceptorNames">
         <list>
            <value>hijackBeforeMethodBean</value>
         </list>
     </property>
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue..
Instead of 
     @Autowired
      Dao b;
I have use the proxy bean
      @Autowired
      Dao proxy;